# CFSocketConnectToAddress and unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: iphone, sockets, bonjour

I am somewhat new to iPhone dev and I have been getting unrecognized selector when I call CFSocketConnectToAddress in this code.  I think it might be something basic that I am doing wrong.  Any idea?

this is the complete error I get.

NSInvalidArgumentException
unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3922170

0x3922170 is the calling class.

```
- (BOOL)connect
```

{
    CFSocketRef mySocket = CFSocketCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM,IPPROTO_UDP, 0, socketCallback, NULL);

```
@try {
    CFDataRef data = (CFDataRef)[_netService addresses]; 
    CFSocketConnectToAddress(mySocket, data, 500);

}
@catch (NSException * e) {
    NSLog([e name]);
    NSLog([e reason]);
}


//char joke[] = "Why did the chicken cross the road?";
//CFSocketError err = CFSocketSendData(mySocket, joke, (strlen(joke)+1), 10);
return true;
```

}

void socketCallback (
                     CFSocketRef s,
                     CFSocketCallBackType callbackType,
                     CFDataRef address,
                     const void *data,
                     void *info)
{

}

Comment: You should give the full error message and probably the code for your socketCallback function as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was kind of hard to track because NSInvalidArgumentException is an odd error message for this error.  But what went wrong was that I had not resolved the NSNetService yet and the addresses array was empty.  If you call CFSocketCreate with an empty adress array you will get  that error.